# Find a function $f(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$ with arclength $(x+1)^2$

Tags: calculus, functions, arc-length

> Give an analytic definition for a function $f(x)$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ for which the arclength from $0$ to $d$ is always $(d+1)^2$.

I’m generally pretty competent with calculus, and I think that my setup ought to be $$(d+1)^2=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^d \sqrt{1+f’(x)^2}dx$$ But I’m kind of lost as to how to actually evaluate this. For one thing, I know that the arclength integral usually has no “nice” antiderivative, but I don’t think that’s a problem because I’m just asking about a case in which it *does*. Next, I think the function has some sort of vertical asymptote at $0$ (because at $x=\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily close to $0$, the arclength is already $(1+\varepsilon)^2>1$, and in particular $>\varepsilon$). Otherwise, I’m pretty much stumped. I could maybe take the derivative of both sides? But then I don’t know how to show that the derivative necessarily commutes inside the limit, and I’m not sure what to do with what would come out of that anyway.

I got this question by modifying a similar one asked on a math LinkedIn group that asked about arclength $d^2$, for which I noted that the arclength would by shorter than that of a straight line for $0<x<1$, so no such function could exist. But I’m pretty sure no similar argument would work for this function because $(x+1)^2>x$ (and in particular $(x+1)^2\not<x$) for all real $x$.

Any help or even hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As $f$ is a function, the arc length from $0$ to $0$ cannot be $1$ !

Comment: That's why I define it on $(0,\infty)$, not $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: That does not make a difference, $x=0$ has null measure.

Comment: Can't you just differentiate both sides with regard to $d,$ to get $4(d+1)^2=1+f'(d)^2.$

Answer (score 2):

Pick $a>0$. Then for all $t>a$, we need
$$ (t+1)^2=(a+1)^2+\int_a^t \sqrt{1+f’(x)^2}dx.$$
Apply $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}$ to both sides:
$$ 2(t+1)=\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}.$$
Solve for $f'(t)$:
$$ f'(t)=\sqrt{(2(t+1))^2-1}=\sqrt{4t^2+8t+3}.$$
Conclude that
$$ f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x\sqrt{4t^2+8t+3}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: Wait- I don’t define $f(x)$ at $0$ because that would cause $\text{arclength}(0,0)=(1+0)^2=1$, which I’m pretty sure is vacuously false. And also I’m pretty sure $\lim_{a\to 0^+} \text{arclength}(0,a)=1$, so there’s an asymptote at 0, which your function doesn’t have. Yet I don’t see a flaw in your solution. What’s going on?

Comment: @LieutenantZipp: why do you accept an answer that you think false ?

Comment: There. Is that better?

Comment: From this $f(x)$ we draw $s(x)=(x+1)^2-1=x(x+1)$. As expected, $s(0)=0$.

Comment: What is $s(x)$?